# Unexpected Behavior from a Linq to EF4 Contains Method

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

On a query of people, this statement should return a number of results that have "And" in their last name-

```
 var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                    .Select(n=> n.LastName)
                                    .Contains("And");
```

It returns no results. If we change it to-

```
var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                   .Select(n=> n.LastName)
                                   .Contains("Anderson");
```

We get all people who has a last name of Anderson.

Obviously it is being translated to SQL as an Equals instead of a Like . Furthermore we modified it to be-

```
var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                   .Select(n=> n.LastName)
                                   .FirstOrDefault()
                                   .Contains("And");
```

That returns all the people who have "And" anywhere in there last name, unfortunately it only checks the first lastname of the person.

```
var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                   .Any(n=> n.LastName
                                   .Contains("And"));
```

Works properly, but we cannot use this the way we would like to.

Comment: You should explain what is the way you want to use because only the last query is correct one.

Comment: you probably *want* fulltext search, which is afaik is not supported in LINQ to Entities, you will have to roll your own using store queries

Comment: We are building dynamic queries and they are all contained within a Where method. The dynamic query consists of 1. Property, 2. ComparisonOperator(==,<=,Contains,etc) 3. Value. We then chain where statements/methods for multiple search expressions. So we try to make everything fit into the Where method so it can be parsed our properly.

Comment: Such generic solution can work only for scalar properties not for navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been working on this dynamic search problem so long...I could not see the forest through the trees.

This does not work because it is an IEnumerable.Contains method which only returns a perfect match.

```
var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                    .Select(n=> n.LastName)
                                    .Contains("And");
```

This works because it is using a String.Contains method.

```
var results = repository.GetQuery().Where(p => p.Names
                                   .Any(n=> n.LastName
                                   .Contains("And"));
```

They are two differnent Contains methods. We go the last one working with our Dynamic Searches.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do this:

```
Select *
From Names
Where LastName like 'And%'
```

The .Contains() method only works with exact matches.  You can use Linq to SQL and specify the exact SQL you are looking for, but that would probably be better with a stored procedure.

This looks like it would be of some assistance: [LINQ to SQL and wildcard searches](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/tquinn/archive/2008/10/03/424.aspx)